# Newly added data into Laravel Request is not included in database insert query

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a new customer record that will belong to the user who created it.

So I will get the user id and add it inside the `$request` before running `Customer::create($request->all())`.

Here is the code:

```
public function store(StoreCustomerRequest $request)
{
    // Get current logged in user's id
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;

    // Add user_id into request
    $request["user_id"] = $userId;

    // Store the newly created customer record
    Customer::create(array_merge($request->all()));
}
```

But after running these code, i found that the `user_id` is not included inside the SQL insert query.

[image]

I tried to use `dd` to print out the content inside `$request->all()` variable and i found that the `user_id` is included.

[image]

Is anyone know what is the problem about the newly added `user_id` is not included inside the SQL insert command.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add "user_id" to the Customer model's fillable array??

Comment: I'd suggest using `$request->validated()`.

Comment: @Arman Thanks for answering, as you mention, I forgot to add inside the model's fillable array. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @XinhaoKoh My pleasure. By the way, it's not a good practice to insert data in this way. Someone can send malicious payloads. Validate data before inserting it to db.  Cause a user is always guilty until proven innocent.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Alternatively you could look at a modelObserver, and add the `user_id` during in the `creating` method.

```
public function store(StoreCustomerRequest $request)
{
    // Store the newly created customer record
    $newCustomer = Customer::make($request->validated());
    $newCustomer->user_id = Auth::id();
    $newCustomer->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mass Assignment!

Include **"user_id"**  to the Customer model's fillable array.